# T-SQL Re-order rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Apolgoies in advance if this is a repeated question, which I failed to look up :(

I have a table that looks like:

```
VersionID DocumentID VersionNo
111       12345         1
112       12345         2
113       12345         3
```

I need to reverse the order of the 'VersionNo' column (all other columns remains unchanged) to as follow:

```
VersionID DocumentID VersionNo
111       12345         3
112       12345         2
113       12345         1
```

I was thinking along the lines of a CTE and ROW_NUMBER() OVER but not been able to get it to work correctly...

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to update this table?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes I want to update the same table, thanks

Comment: Seems like the way to conceptualize this is as two tables; one with Version No's descending, one with VersionID's ascending. Then just copy the Version No's into the one with VersionID's ascending.

Comment: do you want them reversed as described or do you want them renumbered as the chosen solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT VersionID, DocumentID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY VersionID DESC) as VersionNo 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

If you need to update your table, use this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT VersionID, DocumentID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY VersionID DESC) as VersionNoNew
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
UPDATE CTE
SET VersionNo = VersionNoNew
```

Comment: +1 : This will reverse the order. Which also means that any groups with the correct order already will alo get reversed and become the wrong order. Perhaps (depending on what the OP may need) using `OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY VersionID DESC)` would be appropriate? To ensure the new VersionNo is always in the opposite order to the VersionID? ***Also***, you can just do an UPDATE on the CTE directly, without having to do the join. `UPDATE cte SET VersionNo = NewVesionNo` *(Where to call the new field NewVersionNo)*

Comment: Thanks heaps Dems! :) This looks like what I was after. Will test this shortly and let you know. thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT VersionID
, DocumentID 
, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY VersionID DESC) as VersionNo 
FROM Version V
ORDER BY VersionID, DocumentID, VersionNo DESC
```

**Edit**: If you need to update the table, following should work:

```
WITH V as(
    SELECT VersionID
    , DocumentID 
    , VersionNo
    , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY VersionID DESC) as CalculatedVersionNum
    FROM Version
)
UPDATE V
SET VersionNo=CalculatedVersionNum;
```

Comment: +1 : The edit now matches exactly what I also commented on the other answer :)  *[Except that you may need to give the VersionNo a different alias?  I'm not sure if re-using the same name will mask the original field from the update.  I've Never tried it without using a different name in the CTE (Such as NewVersionNo).]*

Answer (score 0):

The current answers does not account for gaps or other values in versionno.

This will reverse the versionno no matter what the value is:

Test data:

```
declare @t table(VersionID int, DocumentID int, VersionNo int)
insert @t 
select 111,12345,1 
union select 112,12345,2 
union select 113,12345,4
```

Update:

```
;with a as
(
  select VersionID, DocumentID, VersionNo, 
  row_number() over (partition by documentid order by VersionID desc) rn1 ,
  row_number() over (partition by documentid order by VersionID asc) rn2 
from @t
)
update a 
set versionno = b.versionno
from a
join a b on a.documentid = b.documentid and a.rn1 = b.rn2

select * from @t
```